# RealmSwift: saving related objects during add()

Tags: swift, realm

In the header for `add(_ object:, update:)` it says, "When added, all child relationships referenced by this object will also be added to the Realm if they are not already in it." This is the behavior I was hoping for, but I'm not 100% clear on what "child relationships" includes/excludes. Which types of Realm relationships are not covered by this behavior?

For example, if I'm adding a `ClassA` object to the realm and I have another unsaved `ClassB` object, will the `ClassB` object be saved:

- If the `ClassB` object points to the `ClassA` object and `ClassA` has a `LinkingObjects` property for `ClassB`?
- If the `ClassB` object is added to a `List` property of `ClassA`?
- If `ClassA` has a to-one relationship variable pointing to the `ClassB` object?

I know that I could set up some sample classes and play around with this to figure out the behavior, but I'd like to have some official clarification if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out this behavior with realm also in the last months. From my experience the child relationships will be saved in your realm database as well. Below you can find the code examples based on your bullet points:

If this is your data model:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ClassA: Object {

    dynamic var uniqueID:String?
    dynamic var someVaraible?


    dynamic var classB:ClassB?
    var list = List<ClassB>()
}
```

> If the ClassB object points to the ClassA object and ClassA has a
>   LinkingObjects property for ClassB?

If you have a `classA` variable `aVar` you can add your object with `aVar.classB = <your classB variable>` in this case nothing will stored in the realm database for now. If you then add a object to realm with

```
 try! realm.write({ 
    realm.add(aVar)
})
```

Realm is going to save both objects (`aVar` and also your `classB` variable).

> If the ClassB object is added to a List property of ClassA?

It is exactly the same behavior like in your first question -> the list of `classB's` (also every single entry of the list will be created in your `classB` database column) will be added to realm, if you add `classA` to realm.

> If ClassA has a to-one relationship variable pointing to the ClassB
>   object?

In this case `classB` variable is already present and you just created a `classA` variable, which is starting to point to an existing `classB` stored entry in realm. (Please correct me, if I misunderstood you).

Comment: This is correct. Just a note: `LinkingObjects` are dynamically calculated at runtime, so there are no explicit relationships related to them that need to be stored in the Realm when objects are added to a Realm.

Comment: @alexWoe89 For the last situation, I'm wondering if during initialization of `ClassA` I also initialize a new `ClassB` and set it as the `classB` variable (before saving either object), will both objects be saved when I call `realm.add(classA)`?

Comment: @blwinters - if you init a new ClassA and you init additionally a new ClassB object during the initialization of ClassA, you are going to create both objects - thats right